# Save table row to a cookie or html5 storage

Tags: html, cookies

What I'm looking to do is have a button on every row of a table that when clicked saves that row to a cookie or HTML5 webstorage (cookies were my initial thought, but it sounds like webstorage might be a better alternative).  I'd also like that row to be removed from this table to show that it was selected.

When I or the user is finished selecting different rows, we would then go to a new page that lists all of the data from the cookie or webstorage in a new table.

Answer (score 0):

Tohaku, you idea does not clear where the data is coming, so you will delete/update/save it? but just trying following are suggestions.

If it is coming from database backend server, than simply make table and add button and assign onclick event in javascript with ajax so each row can be deleted from database.

How do you remove that row, simply put class identifier on td column, make java script to remove that td which is deleted. As for saving you don't need as it is already done in your ajax request. So here there is no need to use any web storage.

As question need more explanation, but if in case you must have to use web storage, you should use indexedDB, as webstorage is depreciated and no more being maintain. Another reason is I have also made full app of mobile on web storage but I found that it don't delete columns individual either it can drop whole table but no individual column deletion. IndexedDB also have many issue and support is in only latest versions but safari/ios does not support it so you also need some shiv solutions.

On first run it will retrieve all your data from database, so use javascript function to load on ready stat of page. Now put same two button with javascript so when delete is pressed it will delete row and save is (as no right explanation so will save in another database). IndexDB is nosql database which is based on object, key storing.

How to do it with indexDB read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB

Comment: Hi Kamal, thanks for your response.  What I'm working with is a classic ASP table generated in Frontpage.  I don't want to send anything back to the DB.  I have a list of items that I would like users to be able to select and when viewing another page they can see all of the items they have selected.

I'm trying to develop a solution for an order form.

Sorry I wasn't clear in my initial question.